# create schtasks to run vbscript on program start

Tags: vbscript, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run `test.vbs` when a Office 15 program such as `Outlook.exe` opens. I would need a to schedule a task and for trigger select on event right? How would I find the event ID of Outlook.exe when it opens?

Could I create this task from command line as well?

Comment: Something like this? http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/11/02/hey-scripting-guy-november-1-2009.aspx